# Should I correct “error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null'" using question mark (?) or exclamation point (!)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

It seems that [Typescript decided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) that the non-null assertion operator is `!`
while the ES2020 standard [opted for `?`](http://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)

They both fix the bug and from what I understand, they do the same. My question is: Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: I would use Typescript syntax when writing typescript, and javascript syntax when writing javascript ... obviously

Comment: Non-null assertion is not the same as optional chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same.

The `!` *asserts* to the type-checker (to TypeScript) that the value is defined.

The `?.` (in the compiled JavaScript) permits further chained access to occur without throwing a JavaScript runtime error.

If you've figured out your types wrong, using `!` incorrectly will result in a runtime error if the value happens not to be defined. Optional chaining, on the other hand, will not throw a runtime error if the value happens to be undefined or null.

Comment: Thanks! I will delve into optional chaining. I have no knowledge on the subject.